# How To Fix The Problem with IEnumerator GetEnumerator C#

Tags: c#

i have start to code C# and i have a little problem with my application, it's show me the error code:

CS1674  WPF C# 'IEnumerator': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable' or implement a suitable 'Dispose' method.

I don't know how to fix that.

My code is:

```
    using (IEnumerator enumerator = this.listViewBoxes.Items.GetEnumerator())
                        {
                            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                            {
                                object obj = enumerator.Current;
                                ListViewItem listViewItem = (ListViewItem)obj;
                                int num5 = 0;
                                int num6 = 0;
                                try
                                {
                                    if (listViewItem.Tag.ToString() == "HEAD")
                                    {
                                        num5 = this.displayBox.Width / 2;
                                        num6 = num + int.Parse(this.offsetHead.Text) * 5;
                                    }
                                    else if (listViewItem.Tag.ToString() == "BODY")
                                    {
                                        num5 = this.displayBox.Width / 2;
                                        num6 = num + int.Parse(this.offsetBody.Text) * 5;
                                    }
                                    else if (listViewItem.Tag.ToString() == "ARM0")
                                    {
                                        num5 = this.displayBox.Width / 2 - 25;
                                        num6 = num2 + int.Parse(this.offsetArms.Text) * 5;
                                    }
                                    else if (listViewItem.Tag.ToString() == "ARM1")
                                    {
                                        num5 = this.displayBox.Width / 2 + 25;
                                        num6 = num2 + int.Parse(this.offsetArms.Text) * 5;
                                    }
                                    else if (listViewItem.Tag.ToString() == "LEG0")
                                    {
                                        num5 = this.displayBox.Width / 2 - 10;
                                        num6 = num3 + int.Parse(this.offsetLegs.Text) * 5;
                                    }
                                    else if (listViewItem.Tag.ToString() == "LEG1")
                                    {
                                        num5 = this.displayBox.Width / 2 + 10;
                                        num6 = num3 + int.Parse(this.offsetLegs.Text) * 5;
                                    }
```

If you need the full code, i can give you on a pastebin or something else
thanks !!

Comment: Can't you convert this whole thing into a `foreach` loop?

Comment: I doubt that listViewBoxes.Items implements IDisposable which is the issue. As @Sweeper says, why not use for each ?

Comment: I have change to foreach but now it's show me: Invalid expression term '=', 'in' expected

Comment: What do you think the purpose of wrapping your `GetEnumerator` call in a `using` statement is?

Comment: @Sakira57 Show us the code with the for each so we can see what the issue is

Comment: Does: `foreach (ListViewItem listViewItem in this.listViewBoxes.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>()) { int num5 = 0; int num6 = 0; try { ... } [...] }` work?

Answer (score 2):

Is because the non generic `IEnumerator` does not implement `IDisposable`. Just remove the `using`.

```
var enumerator = this.listViewBoxes.Items.GetEnumerator();
```

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerator doesn't inherit IDispoable so it cannot be used with using statement.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this whole thing should be re-written entirely and I would certainly recommend using a `foreach` loop here as well.

Also I see nothing calling on the `Dispose()` method from `IDisposable` but if you need to add it from what I can see here at least I would say try creating a local variable and casting your `enumerator` object to `IDisposable` like so:

```
IDisposable disposable = (IDisposable)enumerator;

//example of calling Dispose()

disposable?.Dispose();
```

Note the `?.` operator. It is important to check for `null` here and in this example we're using null propagation since there is a chance that enumerator object instance does not implement `IDisposable`.

You may even want to surround the last statement in a `try-catch` loop similar to this:

```
try
{
    disposable?.Dispose();
}

catch (NullreferenceException ex)
{
   // insert logic to handle null references in here.
}
```

If that doesn't help I'll need a little more elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

As some have pointed out, IEnumerable doesn't implement IDisposable, and it would probably be a good idea to use foreach instead.

Information on foreach: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in

I, personally would also use a switch-statement instead of your if-else chain.

So with those changes the code would look something like this:

```
foreach (ListViewItem listViewItem in this.listViewBoxes.Items)
{
    int num5 = 0;
    int num6 = 0;
    try
    {
        switch (listViewItem.Tag.ToString())
        {
            case "HEAD":
                num5 = this.displayBox.Width / 2;
                num6 = num + int.Parse(this.offsetHead.Text) * 5;
                break;    
            case "BODY":
                num5 = this.displayBox.Width / 2;
                num6 = num + int.Parse(this.offsetBody.Text) * 5;
                break;    
            case "ARM0":
                num5 = this.displayBox.Width / 2 - 25;
                num6 = num2 + int.Parse(this.offsetArms.Text) * 5;
                break;    
            case "ARM1":
                num5 = this.displayBox.Width / 2 + 25;
                num6 = num2 + int.Parse(this.offsetArms.Text) * 5;
                break;    
            case "LEG0":
                num5 = this.displayBox.Width / 2 - 10;
                num6 = num3 + int.Parse(this.offsetLegs.Text) * 5;
                break;    
            case "LEG1":
                num5 = this.displayBox.Width / 2 + 10;
                num6 = num3 + int.Parse(this.offsetLegs.Text) * 5;
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Exception handling
    }
}
```